# show loader gif until download is started in browser

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, browser, download

I'm using `saveSvgAsPng` in angular 4 and wanna show a loader gif until image(.png) is ready to download but something like this is not working correctly and both of the code lines are been executed exactly after each other:

```
svgToImageConverter() {
    this.showLoader = true;
    saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById('main'), 'diagram.png');
    this.showLoader = false;
}
```

I think I need something like Subscribe and change loader boolean before finishing its scope but here in `saveSvgAsPng` I have no idea!

Thanks

Comment: what is ```saveSvgAsPng``` ?

Comment: https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng

Comment: The png seems to be generated almost instantaneously. Is a loader needed?

this.showLoader = true;
this.showLoader = false;

Putting these two lines in this way creates no difference due to the way the Eventloop works in the browser

Comment: No; The production time of the png is proportional to the contents of the svg, the larger the svg size, the longer the production time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `svgAsPngUri = (el, options, done) => {}` and changed `this.showLoader` in `done function`.

svgAsPngUri creates base64 and with [this](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/)
 help, I changed `base64` to `png` file.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your line with this:
**saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("main"), "diagram.png", 3);**
Hope this works!

Comment: what does it do exactly?